# how to store value of form data store in some variable in golang

Tags: go

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(0)
parent := r.Form.Get("parent")
fmt.Println(parent)
Path = "/" + parent + "" + name``
fmt.Println(Path)
```

parent print nothing.Could anyone please tell me how to store a form value to a variable

Answer (score 1):

If you are using net/http

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // fmt.Fprintln(w, "Email : ", r.PostForm.Get("email"))
    // fmt.Fprintln(w, "Password : ", r.PostForm.Get("password"))

    email := r.PostForm.Get("email")
    password := r.PostForm.Get("password")

    finalValue := fmt.Sprintf("%s and %s", email, password)

    // fmt.Println(finalValue)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, finalValue)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error Starting the HTTP Server : ", err)
        return
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this way but still it shows nil and there is no error while parsing the form

Comment: where are you getting nil?

Comment: Is is possible for you to show full code?